# Children access for a multiple li in ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, children

I want to change the class of `ul` inside the *ul.navigator* trying to change it only on the one `li` I click. But this doesn't change anything, doesn't work. some help?

```js
$('.navigator').children('li ul').each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
    $(this).addClass('closed');
    $(this).removeClass('opened');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('opened');
    $(this).removeClass('closed');
  }
});
```

```css
.opened {
  color: green
}
.closed {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigator">
  <li class="elem1">
    <span>Element 1</span>
    <ul class="opened">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="elem2">
    <span>Element 2 </span>
  </li>
  <li class="elem3">
    <span>Element 3 </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You aren't binding a click event anywhere in your code

Comment: And you've dressed something up as a snippet which isn't, in fact, a snippet. Add the necessary libraries and code to make it runnable (or just use code blocks).

Answer (score 0):

**Better** use with **[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)**

```
   $('.navigator li ul').click(function(){
         $(this).toggleClass('closed');          
    });
```

**or**

**for your way** *to solve the problem like below:*

1. use childern apply with same line `$('.navigator li ul').`
2. Apply `removeclass` before `addClass`.
3. And Don't forget to add jquery library

**Snippet**

```js
$('.navigator li ul').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('opened')){
            $(this).removeClass('opened');
            $(this).addClass('closed');
          
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('opened');
            $(this).removeClass('closed');
        }
    });
```

```css
.opened{color:green}
.closed{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigator">
  <li class="elem1">
    <span>Element 1</span>
    <ul class="opened">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="elem2">
    <span>Element 2 </span>
  </li>
  <li class="elem3">
    <span>Element 3 </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

> The `.find()` and `.children()` methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

```
$('.navigator').find('li ul')
```

*OR*, [Descendant selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$('.navigator li ul')
```

```js
$('.navigator').find('li ul').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
    $(this).addClass('closed');
    $(this).removeClass('opened');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('opened');
    $(this).removeClass('closed');
  }
});
```

```css
.opened {
  color: green
}
.closed {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigator">
  <li class="elem1">
    <span>Element 1</span>
    <ul class="opened">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="elem2">
    <span>Element 2 </span>
  </li>
  <li class="elem3">
    <span>Element 3 </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$('.navigator > li').on('click', function() {
  $('.navigator').children('li ul').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
      $(this).addClass('closed');
      $(this).removeClass('opened');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('opened');
      $(this).removeClass('closed');
    }
  });
});
```

This way, when an `li` directly under `.navigator` is clicked, your code will fire.

Answer (score 0):

**using** `toggle` **Function**

```
$('.navigator li').click(function(){
             $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('closed');          
        });
```

**Live Demo** **<kbd>[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/gsxd6mkz/)</kbd>**

**snippet**

```js
$('.navigator li').click(function(){
             $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('closed');          
        });
```

```css
.closed
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <ul class="navigator">
      <li class="elem1">
        <span>Element 1</span>
        <ul class="opened">
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="elem2">
        <span>Element 2 </span>
      </li>
      <li class="elem3">
        <span>Element 3 </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```